# how to set limit of calendar to some date and increase and decrease date on click of a button to same limit in android

Tags: java, android, date

i want create such functionality where user can choose date between today's date to 30 days after today's date so i set max date and min date. and plus i want a functionality where i am having two buttons one to increase date and another to decrease date and from those two buttons also user can choose date between today's date to 30 days after today's date but problem is when someone is clicking on button set max date and min date is not working and in date picker dialog first time it is working fine but next time someone is clicking on calendar it is showing 30 days from that date but i don't want that i want to show today's date and 30 days after that date.

to set max date and min date

```
 try {
            pickerDialog = com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(MainActivity.this,
                    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            pickerDialog.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

            pickerDialog.setMaxDate(calendar);

            pickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker Dialog");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

to increase date and decrease date

```
 ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                calendarSh.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendarSh.getTime());

                Log.v("PREVIOUS DATE : ", formattedDate);
                tvDate.setText(formattedDate);
            }
        });

        ivNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                calendarSh.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
                formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendarSh.getTime());

                Log.v("NEXT DATE : ", formattedDate);
                tvDate.setText(formattedDate);
                ivBack.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.  First, let's consider the date picker. In your code, you are using some variable `calendar`, which is initialised externally to your date picker intialisation code.  When setting up your date picker, you add 30 days to it - but then you are reusing this variable again next time - so adding another 30 days to it - an so on.  Instead you should initialise it internally.  The code would be something like this:

```
try {
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    pickerDialog = com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            MainActivity.this,
            newCalendar .get(Calendar.YEAR),
            newCalendar .get(Calendar.MONTH),
            newCalendar .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );

    pickerDialog.setMinDate(newCalendar);
    newCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
    pickerDialog.setMaxDate(newCalendar);
    pickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker Dialog");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, when you use buttons to increase/decrease dates, your min/max from the date picker do not apply anymore - you have to check against min/max every time.  You code could look something like this:

```
final Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
final Calendar.maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
maxDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (calendarSh.after(minDate)) {
            calendarSh.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendarSh.getTime());

            Log.v("PREVIOUS DATE : ", formattedDate);
            tvDate.setText(formattedDate);
        }
    }
});

ivNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (calendarSh.before(maxDate)) {
            calendarSh.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
            formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendarSh.getTime());

            Log.v("NEXT DATE : ", formattedDate);
            tvDate.setText(formattedDate);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: works perfect ! thanks and +1 for explaining in easy way .